# Is there any difference between "I won't do" "I'm not going to do" and "I am not doing" when refusing to do something you've been told to?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between *I won't do* *I'm not going to do* and *I am not doing* when refusing to do something you've been told to? For example:

> Sara asked me to do her homework. **I won't do** that.
>
> Sara asked me to do her homework. **I'm not going to do** that.
>
> Sara asked me to do her homework. **I'm not doing** that.

Comment: To me 1) is neutral, 2) is slightly more polite and hesitant / implies some consideration behind the decision, and 3) is rather haughty and defiant. But that's just my personal reading of it. Pretty sure all have the same meaning in this context, just with different undertones.

Answer (score 0):

1. Making his decision of his willingness toward whether to do her homework at the time of speaking.
2. Showing his plan that has already been made.
3. Telling the listener that the future about whether to do her homework is firmly set.